# GridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle doesnt seem to be accurate

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a simple helper procedure to align some controls horizontally to the DataGridView columns but there seems to be some inconsistencies with the code, my helper is very simple and I don't think its the cause, I think its an internal problem somewhere and I'm hoping someone has experienced this and has a fix that doesn't include manually offsetting locations.

the helper is..

```
Private Sub AlignComboToGridCell(ByRef GridViewObject As DataGridView, ByRef ComboObject As ComboBox, GridCellIndex As Integer)
    With GridViewObject
        ''If Not .DataSource = Nothing Then
        If .RowCount > 0 Then
                Try
                    ComboObject.Left = .GetCellDisplayRectangle(GridCellIndex, .FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex, True).Left
                    ComboObject.Width = .GetCellDisplayRectangle(GridCellIndex, .FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex, True).Width
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If
        ''End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm using this with a TabControl that has several tabs all with DataGridViews, they basically all have the same format and just display different information. but the controls sometimes are not aligned correctly and are moved horizontally (left) to far........ only by a few pixels but its enough to look bad...... I have no idea why, its working on other Grids. any ideas?

Comment: Get rid of the empty Try catch block as a starter. If there is an error at the moment you wont know about it.

Comment: The other thing to look at is the timing of when you're making your calls. Only 1 tab is visible at a time. Are the background tabs laying out correctly and the foreground ones not? And are your columns setup to autosize? Do you call your handler again after they are laid out.

Comment: At what point do you apply this formatting?  Working with a `TabPage`  can be frustrating as: ["Controls contained in a TabPage are not created until the tab page is shown"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7).

Comment: Tnx for your replies.... 1) I used the try catch initially because I used to get an error if I scrolled to fast (using older code not here) I just left it there just in case. 2) these calles are made on form, column resize and initially when the table is loaded..... bare in mind this code works fine on other tables. 3) this formatting is applied last after the table update, adding controls etc etc.......

Comment: all its supposed to do it align comboboxes to the columns for filtering... but on some tables its to the left about 10-20 pixels or so...... again its an old problem I used to fix with an offset of the left position, I'm just wandering why it does it on 1 table and not the other....

Comment: all tables are populated with the same routine, they all have the same properties, nothing is changed at runtime other that the datasource, they share the same anchor, everything is the same....... I just don't get it, its not that a columns is scrolled slightly hidden.... do I really have to manually offset it for each pc?